# Can a class name be used as a datatype for an array?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, nullpointerexception

I tried executing the following code

```
public class Phonebook {
    String name;
    long phno;
}

public class Store {
    public static void main(String args[]) {        
        Phonebook p[] = new Phonebook[10];

        p[0].name = "vasvi";
        p[0].phno = 123456;
        p[1].name = "abcd";
        p[2].phno = 903747;

        System.out.println(p[0].name + " " + p[1].name);
    }
}
```

This code when executed gives the `NullPointerException`. I don't seem to understand why.  I have learnt that classes are user defined data types. So I'm really confused why such an exception would arise?

Comment: Your array is empty, you never put `Phonebook`  objects in it . Sure it has 10 slots, but each one contains `null` .

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have not initialized you array.